# Immersive mode failing: Is it the code, or the virtual device?

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement my app to work that, so long as your finger is on the screen, immersive mode is activated. On my Galaxy S5, it works just as I described. On BlueStacks and an AVD of Nexus 10, however, it doesn't work. Instead, only every other `ACTION_DOWN` is received by `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`.

When some devices/virtual devices work and others don't, I find it very difficult to tell what's wrong. Is there something wrong with my code that triggers the immersive mode? I bassically just copied it from [here](https://developer.android.com/samples/ImmersiveMode/src/com.example.android.immersivemode/ImmersiveModeFragment.html).

I have found though that if I remove the line `newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;`, then `onTouchEvent` is always triggered on the Nexus 10, but of course the navigation bar isn't hidden.

onTouchEvent:

```
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        points.add(new FPoint(event.getX(), event.getY()));

        if (event.getY() > closeY - 35 && event.getY() < closeY && event.getX() < 50)
            tActivity.finish();

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && isImmersiveModeEnabled)
            toggleHideyBar(tActivity);
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && !isImmersiveModeEnabled)
            toggleHideyBar(tActivity);

        return true;
    }
```

toggleHideyBar:

```
public void toggleHideyBar(ScreenTouchTest sttActivity)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
        return;

    // The UI options currently enabled are represented by a bitfield.
    // getSystemUiVisibility() gives us that bitfield.
    int uiOptions = sttActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
    int newUiOptions = uiOptions;
    isImmersiveModeEnabled = ((uiOptions | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY) == uiOptions);

    // Navigation bar hiding: Backwards compatible to ICS.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
    {
        newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    }

    // Status bar hiding: Backwards compatible to Jellybean
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
    {
        newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    }

    // Immersive mode: Backward compatible to KitKat.
    // Note that this flag doesn't do anything by itself, it only augments
    // the behavior of HIDE_NAVIGATION and FLAG_FULLSCREEN.
    // For the purposes of this
    // sample all three flags are being toggled together.
    // Note that there are two immersive mode UI flags, one of which is
    // referred to as "sticky".
    // Sticky immersive mode differs in that it makes the navigation and
    // status bars semi-transparent, and the UI flag does not get cleared when the user
    // interacts with the screen.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18)
    {
        newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
    }

    sttActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(newUiOptions);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that `^=` is wrong here try using `|=`. You are `xor` the values I think you want to `or` them.

Comment: @rekire: Didn't work.